# Using SSH in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ssh

I want to write an Extension for the google chrome browser which reads some links from a website and copy these links into a file. I want to send this file via ssh to another computer in my local network.

How can I setup and use a ssh connection in my chrome extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897649/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-ssh-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean scp, not ssh, here are your options:

- Set up a WebSocket proxy. Write JavaScript to send the XHR-fetched ArrayBuffer. WebSockets can go over SSL, so you'll probably be satisfied with that rather than implementing SSH in JavaScript (and then scp over that).
- Same idea but an HTTP proxy. This would be pretty painful. See [Web-based SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) for overview.
- Write a Chrome App, thereby getting access to `chrome.sockets`. Implement SSH in JavaScript. See [paramikojs](https://github.com/mimecuvalo/paramikojs) to get started.
- Chrome App, Native Client. This can actually work; see Secure Shell. Add scp functionality.

The Chrome-App-based solutions raise a separate question of how to get the web content. You might be able to use Chrome Apps webview. Or you can message the content between the app and a Chrome Extension.

There are probably other approaches as well. But you get the idea: you have a lot of coding ahead of you.